# Running multiple VMs in one harddrive

Tags: virtual-machine, ssd, hyper-v, windows-server-2012

I have Windows 2012 running on Intel i7 4770K, SSD 180 GB and 32GB RAM.
Also that machine has 1TB HDD. Windows is installed on SSD. Currently 3 VMs on HyperV running and I need another VM. Can I install all of them in one 1TB HDD and running all 4 at the same time? Will this be a performance issue for all VMs? Will it help performance if I install them in two different HDDs?

Answer (score 0):

Currently I'm doing my internship at an organisation that provides IT classes to people. One of these classes is doing virtualization.

The computers are an i7, 32GB RAM and 500GB HDD. They are running the host (W7), 2x Windows 2008 R2 Server (VM), W7 (VM) and a W8.1 (VM). I have not yet gotten any reports about slow performances. It's all about the amount of RAM you give to each of the devices.

I would say the only way to be sure, in your case, is to test it out. But as I said in the above, we haven't had any problems so far with it!